# put different name for one attribut in sql

Tags: java, sql

I need to create a database for flight booking.
In the database, should I create 3 attributes for the class (first class, business class, economy class) or one attribute is enough because I want to link it to java, so I can select one of the classes

Comment: This question is not clear. What are attributes in the database? columns of tables? You should maybe show us the database structure options you are evaluating, so we can help you choose one.

Comment: In the database I want to create a table called Plane
in it I ant to add an attribute for the class
 (first, ...)

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it would be sufficient to have just a 'class' attribute/column. This could have  different values representing the different classes. You could also have a lookup table with definition of these class numerical values.

e.g. 
Table: bookings

```
|id  | class | ....
100  |  1    | ....
```

Table: booking_classes

```
|class_id | class_name   | ....
| 1       |  first class | ....
```

In this approach, you don't have to worry about altering table column for possible new class type in future.

Answer (score 0):

this is related what you are doing. before thinking about java and classes you have to look at the design stage that is not connected with the Java issue, when you finish it you can start with the Java Code after that.

You can notice that when you see ERD for DataBases and UML for classes (java or c#), so you are mixing between two "almost" separated parts!

Answer (score 0):

You could have table FlightBookings with columns FlightBookingID, Description, BookingClassID
and another table BookingClasses with columns BookingClassID, Name.
BookingClassID in the first table references the BookingClassID primary key in the second.

In your table BookingClasses, you can store your values First class, Business class, Economy class.

In java code you would then have:

```
public class FlightBooking {
    private int _id; 
    private BookingClass _bookingClass;
    …//appropriate setter and getters for both of the attributes
}

public class BookingClass {
    private int _id; 
    private String _name;
    …//appropriate setter and getters for both of the attributes
}
```

This could be one approach. Or you do not have a BookingClasses table and have a simple string as the class column like:
FlightBookings with columns FlightBookingID, Description, BookingClass
AND then map this third column in java code as enumerations, where the values of the enums are First, Business and Economy.

The first solution is better for database developers, because they know what is what and the second is for java developers and it is more performant because no JOIN SQL statement is needed. But it is also a readable solution in case you use hibernate and store the values in a database as strings (for example: BUSINESS)